# CMake linking Boost: cannot find -lboost_program_options

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I want to use Boosts support for command line flags in C++ on Linux. I use CMake to build the application, but I get a error "cannot find -lboost_program_options". The library boost_program_options was build independently using bjam, and the libraries are in the stage/lib subdirectory of the boost directory.

**What does work**: A solution is to add the stage/lib library using link_directories, but the CMake [manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) states:

> Note that this command is rarely necessary. Library locations returned by find_package() and find_library() are absolute paths.

So that should not be nescessary.

**What I want to have working:**

Using find_package should be enough, but that doesn't work, here's the CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(inp_manipulation)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(includes lib/boost_1_62_0 lib/)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "lib/boost_1_62_0")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "lib/boost_1_62_0/stage/lib")

find_package(Boost 1.62.0)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
set(MAIN_FILE main.cpp)
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(inp_manipulation ${MAIN_FILE} ${SOURCE_FILES} )
target_link_libraries(inp_manipulation -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ boost_program_options)
```

**Question**

Where is the mistake in the CMakeLists?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must tell cmake that you require the specific component library from boost:

```
find_package(Boost 1.62.0 COMPONENTS program_options)
```

Second, always use the output variables from BoostFind.cmake

```
target_link_libraries(inp_manipulation -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html

Output variables are:

> Boost_FOUND            - True if headers and requested libraries were found
>
> **Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS**     - Boost include directories
>
> **Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS**     - Link directories for Boost libraries
>
> **Boost_LIBRARIES**        - Boost component libraries to be linked

etc

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this was indeed missing.

Comment: @DA-- it's not entirely your fault - the documentation for cmake is shocking - which is a shame as it's fantastic.
Another note: avoid platform-specific link libraries. Use the cmake abstract versions where possible.

Comment: FWIW, I did *not* need to have "COMPONENTS program_options" in the find_package command; it was the `${BOOST_LIBRARIES}` that helped me.